# Next JS: Right way to fetch client-side only data in a Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a functional component. Basically, the page consists of a form - where I need to populate some existing data into the form and let the user update it.

I'm using a hook that I wrote to handle the forms. What it does is this

```
 const [about, aboutInput] = useInput({
    type: 'textarea',
    name: 'About you',
    placeholder: 'A few words about you',
    initialValue: data && data.currentUser.about,
  })
```

`about` is the value and `aboutInput` is the actual input element itself. I can pass an initialValue to it too.

At the beginning of the component I'm fetching the data like so:

`const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER_QUERY)`

This only is executed on the client side and on the server side `data` is undefined.

Hence this code only works when I navigate to the page through a Link component from another client-side page.

It doesn't work for:

1. When I go the URL directly
2. When I navigate to this page from another SSR page(which uses getInitailProps)

I don't want to use lifecycle methods/class component(since I'm using hooks, and want to keep using the functional component.

Is there a nice way to achieve this in Next JS and keep using functional component?

Answer (score 5):

You can fetch **client-side** only data using the **useEffect Hook**.

Import it first from `react`

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
```

Usage in the component looks like follows

```js
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    // clean-up functions
  }
}, []);
```

The first argument Is a function and you can make your API calls inside this.

The second argument to the **useEffect** will determine when the **useEffect** should be ***triggered***. If you pass an empty array [ ], then the **useEffect** will only be fired when the component Mounts. If you want the **useEffect** to fire if any props change then pass such props as a dependency to the array.

If you want GET_CURRENT_USER_QUERY from the query string you can pass the argument from the **getInitailProps** and read this as props in the **useEffect** array dependency.

Comment: I also tried with useEffect, in that case I was confused on how would I use the variables inside useEffect in the render function. For example.
I have something like this inside my useEffect
const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_CURRENT_USER_QUERY)
    const [name, nameInput] = useInput({
      type: 'text',
      name: 'Name',
      placeholder: 'Your name',
      initialValue: data && data.currentUser.name,
    })
In return of the component I need to use nameInput now. Because the hook returns my component itself.
I have a scope issue with the variable. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I see you mentioned `getInitailProps`. So you probably know what it does and its [caveats](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps#caveats).  If you want the data to be defined on server side, why not use `getInitailProps` on the page which the form is in. That way you can retrieve the data from `props` and pass it to your form component. It should work either directly visiting the url or visiting from your other pages.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But in the above case, I'm trying to fetch data on the client-side as server-side fetching is not necessary.

Comment: I had the same scenario and what I did was to provide sensible default/initialValue to my component and  use `useEffect` to fetch data and populate it. Something like `useEffect(()=>{fetchData(), populateForm()},[])` this will only be called once on client-side.

Answer (score 0):

The question content is slightly confusing, I am not sure why a form is involved, so I'll try to answer based on the title.

The best practices to fetch data client-side are described in the newer version of React documentation. In particular, the "[You might not need an effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data)" page is a precious source of information.

It advocates two things:

1. use library for client-side data fetching, it's most often not worth it to roll your own solution
2. if you don't want a library, implement cleaning properly, as demonstrated by the `useData` hook:

```js
// From React documentation
function useData(url) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    let ignore = false;
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        if (!ignore) {
          setData(json);
        }
      });
    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [url]);
  return data;
}
```

Usage:

```js
function SearchResults({ query }) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const params = new URLSearchParams({ query, page });
  const results = useData(`/api/search?${params}`);

  function handleNextPageClick() {
    setPage(page + 1);
  }
  // ...
}
```

As a bonus, if you want to also display data during the server-render and the first client-render, you can mix server-side data fetching using Next.js built-in features, and use the server data to warn the client-side cache.

For instance in SWR, this is done via [the fallback option](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs). I call this pattern "client-server relaying" in my [Next.js course](https://www.newline.co/courses/blazing-fast-next.js-with-react-server-components), because the server value is passed to the client like a relay. Then the client code handles interactivity: refetching on mutation, polling etc.